# Is it all right to call CQ to a foreign country in their own language?

Tags: legal, procedure, united-kingdom, international-operating

I have been asked by an Arabic speaker here in UK if it is legal, or desirable, to call CQ in Arabic if his beam is directed that way.

Please, what answer should I give? Is there a general rule that covers all calls to a foreign country?

Comment: Use CW (aka Morse Code) -- along with Q-signals, language specific QSOs are not required.  But, I would be very surprised if there were any restrictions on  language.  [Not an answer -- just a comment].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok.

Hams may use any language they want if both sides agree to use it.

If ham calls CQ in Arabic that is invitation to use that language in QSO.

Answer (score 4):

> if it is **legal**, or desirable

Radio Amateurs may use any language which they can speak. I am not aware that there are any countries where the use of, or the not-use of, a particular language is stipulated in the license. But IANAL, and there are many countries.

> if it is legal, or **desirable**

If the licensed Amateur wants to use his own native language, then the answer is simple; 'yes' it is desirable for that person. Using a language other than English will restrict the CQ, and with that the QSO, to only those who speak the same language.

We will have to understand that there are lots of people, who do not speak English, and will communicate in their own native language. My uncle, PD0FFS(SK) only spoke Dutch, but he still had a lifetime of fun in the hobby. He did try to make some international contacts using "Pigeon English" and sometimes this would work, sometimes it didn't, and sometimes the other party would be rude for not being able to clearly speak English (!!)

This rudeness for not-speaking English can still be heard on the bands today, in fact I would believe that it is increasing.

I would therefore ask everyone to be courteous for non-native-English speakers.

(*I will get off my soap-box now*)